# facebook's all.js is too big, is there a alternative

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facbook's all.js is too big. I just need the login part of it. Is there a way. Also is there a way to check if the user is loggedin without using all.js on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Facebook's all.js is too big.

Is it? They are doing everything they can to improve the download size of their script (not only for that particular one, but also for scripts embedded f.e. in the like button iframe, there’s some interesting blog posts about that on the net). It’s as big as it needs to be for the functionality it offers.

> I just need the login part of it. Is there a way.

No, there is no way of just picking the cherries out of it. They have assembled all the functionality that is most commonly used in websites that use the Facebook API in that one script. Splitting it up into multiple scripts so that everyone could only load “just what they need” would hit performance even worse, if people had to embed multiple scripts if they needed more than one functionality.

> Also is there a way to check if the user is loggedin without using all.js on the client side.

Only server-side then.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to do your entire development with all.js

Then run your code through a dead path removal script (Google Closure comes to mind).
This will remove everything that is not needed in your code workflow.

Comment: The script in question (all.js) is hosted at Facebook.

Comment: @steveax nothing stops it from being hosted locally.

Comment: @steveax There are of course pros and cons. But he wanted to know what he could do.